# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException - jndiName

Tags: java, tomcat, jetty, applicationcontext

I want to switch from jetty to tomcat. I get NameNotFoundException because tomcat not found jndiName that is in jetty-web.xml and used in applicationContext.xml.

part of my applicationContext.xml:

```
    <bean id="clarityDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" depends-on="i18nFactoryProvider">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/clarityDS"/>
    </bean>
```

part of jetty-web.xml

```
    <New id="clarityds" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg>java:comp/env/jdbc/clarityDS</Arg>
    <Arg>
        <New class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
            <Set name="connectionCachingEnabled">true</Set>
            <Set name="dataSourceName">clarityDS</Set>
            <Set name="URL"><SystemProperty name="clarityDS.url"/></Set>
            <Set name="user"><SystemProperty name="clarityDS.username"/></Set>
            <Set name="password"><SystemProperty name="clarityDS.password"/></Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
    </New>
```

I know that jetty-web.xml load after all files.

anyone can help me?

- jetty-web.xml deployed in WEB-INF
- applicationContext.xmk deployed in WEB-INF/classes/spring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add resource to tomcat `context.xml` and solved problem.

[Run java web apps in embedded containers with Maven, Jetty and Tomcat](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/run-java-web-apps-in-embedded-containers-with-maven-jetty-and-tomcat/)

```
       <Resource
           name="jdbc/clarityDS"
           auth="Container"
           type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           driverClassName="clarity.clarityDS.driverClassName"
           username="clarity.clarityDS.username"
           password="clarity.clarityDS.password"
           url="clarity.clarityDS.url"
           />
```

But i like to use my context.xml in custom path, if it's possible